# How can you sort an array by its' inner array size with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

everyone. I'm very new to this backend thing, and i'm starting to figure out the basics.
I made a basic system of posts and comments on NodeJS and mongoose.
The thing is now i want to get the post with the most comments so in the homepage i can show the most popular ones.

I want to return the posts that have the largest array of comment ids.

I first tried doing this:

```
var mysort = { comments: 1 };

Post.find( {} )
    .sort(mysort)
    .exec( (err, posts)=>{
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                message: 'Error loading posts',

            });
        } 

        return res.status(200).json({
            ok: true,
            posts: posts
        });
});
```

But it just returns the comments in an alphabetical order.

Thank you very much for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Aggregation Framework and [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) operator to create temporary field using [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and then you can use [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) to sort by that field (`-1` means descending order)

```
Post.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            commentsCount: { $size: "$comments" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { commentsCount: -1 }
    }
]).exec( (err, posts)=>{
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                message: 'Error loading posts',

            });
        } 

        return res.status(200).json({
            ok: true,
            posts: posts
        });
});
```